# AngularJS : directive with dynamic template and recursion

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to render an array of items of differing types (i.e. example #1) and for one object type, render a tree of child items, if present.  I'm not clear how I can combine both link and compile methods to achieve my end.  I'm not sure how to move from the link to the compile stage.

Here's the data model that needs to be rendered:

- item1.type = 'type2'
- item2.type = 'type1'
- item3.type = 'tree-root'
  item3.children = []; // array of objects that represent a tree
- item4.type = 'type2'
- item5.type = 'type1'

So, there's a type1.template, a type2.template, a tree-root.template and a tree-node.template.  Rendering the tree-root.template would include a ng-repeat recursive render of the children using the tree-node.template.

1. Here's an example of dynamic template selection based on data type: https://coderwall.com/p/mgtrkg - it uses a link function to select the correct template, and doesn't explicitly include a compile function.

   ```
     angular.module('components', []).
     directive('tumblrPost', ['$compile', '$http', '$templateCache', function($compile, $http, $templateCache) {

       var getTemplate = function(contentType) {
         var templateLoader,
         baseUrl = '/templates/components/tumblr/',
         templateMap = {
           text: 'text.html',
           photo: 'photo.html',
           video: 'video.html',
           quote: 'quote.html',
           link: 'link.html',
           chat: 'chat.html',
           audio: 'audio.html',
           answer: 'answer.html'
         };

         var templateUrl = baseUrl + templateMap[contentType];
         templateLoader = $http.get(templateUrl, {cache: $templateCache});

         return templateLoader;

      }

     var linker = function(scope, element, attrs) {

       var loader = getTemplate(scope.post.type);

       var promise = loader.success(function(html) {
           element.html(html);
       }).then(function (response) {
           element.replaceWith($compile(element.html())(scope));
       });
     }

     return {
       restrict: 'E',
       scope: {
           post:'='
       },
       link: linker
     };
   }]);
   ```
2. Here's an example of recursion in a directive from this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n8dPm/ - it recursively calls compile until it renders the entire tree, and omits a link function.

   ```
           module.directive("tree", function($compile) {
               return {
                   restrict: "E",
                   scope: {family: '='},
                   template: 
                       '<p>{{ family.name }}</p>'+
                       '<ul>' + 
                           '<li ng-repeat="child in family.children">' + 
                               '<tree family="child"></tree>' +
                           '</li>' +
                       '</ul>',
                   compile: function(tElement, tAttr) {
                       var contents = tElement.contents().remove();
                       var compiledContents;
                       return function(scope, iElement, iAttr) {
                           if(!compiledContents) {
                               compiledContents = $compile(contents);
                           }
                           compiledContents(scope, function(clone, scope) {
                                    iElement.append(clone); 
                           });
                       };
                   }
               };
           });
   ```

Comment: Did you know you can use get the content of text/ng-template via cacheTemplate service? Then you can compile it. Otherwise use $http and compile on success

Comment: "Otherwise use $http and compile on success" +1. Good practice in my experience.

Comment: I think this [dynamicTemplate service](https://github.com/BurakAkyildiz/angularJs-dynamic-conditional-templates) helpfull for this case.